# Using queries by Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I try to make complex query as below code.
My goal is to create three different query request statements by

[image]

1. only each one(date or user_name or customer_name)
2. dates and user name
3. dates and customer name.

I tried to make it but I don't know how to do with `whereBetween` method.
I think `when` method should solution instead of `if - else` statements.

How could I do that?

**Controller**

```
 public function jobSearch(Request $request)
    {
       $query = Job::onlyTrashed()
                 ->where('is_trash', 1)
                 ->where( function ($queryByDate) use($request)
                 { 
                     $queryByDate->whereBetween('created_at', array(
                             (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_from'))->startOfDay()),
                             (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_to'))->endOfDay())))
                            ->where('customer_name', 'like', '%'.$request->customer_name.'%')
                            ->orwhere('user_name', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%');
                     })
                 ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc');


        $job_ids = $query->pluck('id')->all();  
        // $job_ids = $query->pluck('id');                



        $jobs = $query->paginate(15);

        if (empty($job_ids)){
            Flash::error('Search result not found.');
            return redirect(route('retrievejobs.index'));
        }

        return view('retrievejobs.index', ['jobs' => $jobs]); 
    }
```

**View**

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto; display: inline-flex;">
    {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form', 'method' => 'get', 'url' => url('/stopjobs/jobsearch'))) !!} 
    {{ Form::input('text', 'datepicker_from', null, ['placeholder' => 'Fra', 'id' => 'datepicker_from']) }}
        &nbsp;
    {{ Form::input('text', 'datepicker_to', null, ['placeholder' => 'Til', 'id' => 'datepicker_to']) }} 
&nbsp;
    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['placeholder' => 'Bruker eller Kunde']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Søke', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm']) !!} 
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make multiple if statements and chain the query according to the if statements.

Example:

```
$query = Job::onlyTrashed()
             ->where('is_trash', 1)
             ->where( function ($queryByDate) use($request)
             { 
                if($request->something){

                 $queryByDate->whereBetween('created_at', array(
                         (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_from'))->startOfDay()),
                         (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_to'))->endOfDay())))
                        ->where('customer_name', 'like', '%'.$request->customer_name.'%')
                        ->orwhere('user_name', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%');
                }else if($request->something else){
                  $queryByDate->whereBetween('created_at', array(
                         (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_from'))->startOfDay()),
                         (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_to'))->endOfDay())))

                        ->orwhere('user_name', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%');
             }
                 })
             ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

You need to set the `$matchCustomerName` and `$matchUsername` variables according to your requirement.

```
public function jobSearch(Request $request)
{
   $query = Job::onlyTrashed()
               ->where('is_trash', 1)
               ->when($request->input('datepicker_from'), function($query) use($request) {
                    $query->whereBetween('created_at', [
                        Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_from'))->startOfDay(),
                        Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_to'))->endOfDay()
                    ]);
               })->when($request->customer_name, function($query) use($request) {
                    $matchCustomerName = true;
                    $query->where('customer_name', 
                                  'like', 
                                  "%{$request->customer_name}%", 
                                  $matchCustomerName ? 'and' : 'or');
               })->when($request->name, function($query) use($request) {
                    $matchUsername = true;
                    $query->where('user_name', 
                                  'like', 
                                  "%{$request->name}%", 
                                  $matchUsername ? 'and' : 'or');
               })->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc');

    $jobs = $query->paginate(15);

    if ($jobs->isEmpty()){
        Flash::error('Search result not found.');
        return redirect(route('retrievejobs.index'));
    }

    return view('retrievejobs.index', ['jobs' => $jobs]); 
}
```

Comment: Undefined variable: matchUsername

Comment: updated the answer. remove the `matchUsername` from `use`

Comment: Your code just working with each user_name or date, not together with them. also can't search by customer_name. :(

Comment: There was a mistake. I have updated the answer. (first parameter passed to `when`).

Comment: still not working correctly, if view file as upper then how to revise that?

Comment: Do you get any errors. What do you mean by `if view file as upper then how to revise that`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168400/discussion-between-chanafdo-and-magnetic).